# SAP HANA: Connect to systemdb on worker/slave node

Tags: database, hana

I have a 2 node sap hana scale-out setup. I'd like to connect on the worker node(Node2) on database systemdb using hdbsql. However I get the below error while connecting on Port 3xx13:

`* -10709: Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=111:Connection refused (localhost:30013))`

On the Master node(Node1), the output of sql `"select * from sys_databases.m_services"` does not show a row for SYSTEMDB on Node2

I am able to access other tenant databases that are distributed across the 2 nodes based on the SQL_PORT value of the above SQL query.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to systemdb on worker nodes with SQL. Only the master node offers an SQL interface and manages all other nodes.